# Modify message label Python GMAIL API

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to send a post request using the Gmail API. However, I could not find in the documentation the name of the parameter I have to use to send the data.

For example, below is a sample of the code I'm using:

```
post_data = {
  "addLabelIds": [
    "123456789"
  ]
}

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
result = service.users().messages().modify(userId=user_id, id=message_id).execute()
```

Any guidance would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: What parameter are you talking about? Do you mean the `user_id`, the `message_id`, or simply how to execute the method? If it's the latter, you would simply use `execute()`: `result = service.users().messages().modify(userId=user_id, id=message_id).execute()`.

Comment: Apologies for not explaining myself clearly. I'm trying to do the following, but with the Gmail API

```import requests
url = "https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/{id}/modify".format(userId=userid, id=message_id)

post_data = {
  "addLabelIds": [
    "123456789"
  ]
}

x = requests.post(url, data = post_data)```

Comment: So you don't want to use the Python API library (see related [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)), and use `requests` instead? What's the reason for that? In any case, you are missing the authentication part. You are trying to access a non-public resource, so you'll have to go through the [OAuth process](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2). Is your question how to do that while using the `requests` module?

Comment: I want to do the opposite: I want to use the Gmail API instead of the `requests` package to send a Post request.
Yes I did not include the authentication part because this part is working fine

Comment: I'm sorry, I still cannot understand your purpose. The code you shared can be used to modify the email, you just need to execute it (as long as you have actually gone through the OAuth process, as you said). What makes you think this is not executing successfully, are you getting any error?

Comment: That's alright. Please see below the error I get:
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/1770f5faa6a9aad9/modify?alt=json returned "No label add or removes specified">

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I didn't notice you were not providing the `body` parameter to your method. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the request `body` as a parameter when calling `modify`, like this:

```
result = service.users().messages().modify(userId=user_id, id=message_id, body=post_data).execute()
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: users.messages.modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/modify)
- [modify(userId=*, id=*, body=None)](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#modify)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I was using the first [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/modify) but I did not have the second [link](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#modify) so thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Also, for this to work for me I had to change from this format:

```
post_data = {
  "addLabelIds": ["123456789"]
}
```

To this format:

```
post_data = {
  "addLabelIds": ["123456789"],
  "removeLabelIds": ["IMPORTANT", "CATEGORY_UPDATES", "INBOX"]
}
```

Looks like the Gmail API needs both the `addLabelIds` and `removeLabelsIds` keys.

With only `addLabelIds` I received the following error from the Gmail API:

> An error occurred: <HttpError 400 when requesting
> https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads/186ce9fdf209a6ec/modify?alt=json
> returned "No label add or removes specified". Details: "[{'message':
> 'No label add or removes specified', 'domain': 'global', 'reason':
> 'invalidArgument'}]">

Comment: It's not correct. You can specify addLabelIds without specifying removeLabelIds.